# Can SSL traffic encrypted with a weak cypher be bruteforced?

Tags: encryption, tls, brute-force, tls-intercept

Take the following scenario:

- Attacker performs a man-in-the-middle attack on Client, redirecting the DNS records of www.example.com to point to a malicious server
- Client connects to the malicious server that completes the SSL handshake using the public key of www.example.com, and negotiates a weak cypher, eg. DES 56/56
- Client sends a request to the malicious server, which is logged

At this point, the server disconnects, and the client never gets a response. Is it possible for the attacker to bruteforce the contents of the client's request?

Comment: Attacker cannot complete the handshake himself without the server privatekey and cannot alter the handshake between the client and legit server (because of Finished), plus any TLS (no longer SSL) implementation today that agrees to singleDES is defective -- it's been withdrawn for TLS since 2008 and by NIST even earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The scenario you exposed is not possible for the reasons described by Dave Thompson as in comments.

However, the concept you are talking about is called a SSL downgrade attack and occurs when the eavesdropper is able to alter the initial handshake. For exemple: breaking the connection to force the client to retry with lower SSL/TLS version: https://p16.praetorian.com/blog/man-in-the-middle-tls-ssl-protocol-downgrade-attack

At this point, crypto-attacks are possible but they don't actually rely on bruteforce, except if a very weak cipher is used, but forcing user to use weak SSL version AND weak cipher suite is pretty hard. Most of the time, a cryptographic implementation flaw is present in older versions of SSL and allow to decrypt data in a certain way.

If one day you can intercept DES 56 bits stream, you can assume that, yes, it can be bruteforced with modern computer and in a easier way with dedicted cloud computing